# How do I echo a variable with a star in it with added text?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, output, echo

So I am creating a variable and I want to echo it with an addition to the end like so:

I have a file: `Filename-08-10-2017.txt`

I create a variable:

```
myvariable=Filename*.txt
```

When I echo that variable:

```
echo $myvariable
```

it outputs `Filename-08-10-2017.txt`

But I want to change the name to .zip

So I am trying to go:

`echo $myvariable.zip` and have it output `Filename-08-10-2017.txt.zip`

however it outputs:

```
Filename*.txt.zip
```

How do I go about having it output the way I want?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I kind of figured it out.

I saved a new variable as $($myvariable) which saved the output.

Comment: Do you expect it to return a single file? If so why not just use the full filename, if not use a loop.

Comment: I have one file, but I am using a script to generate and delete files, but then I am trying to zip them up with a password.

Answer (score 0):

The file name comes from glob expansion. If you want to iterate all files by using glob expansion,  you can :

```
myvariable=Filename*.txt
for f in $myvariable; do echo $f; done
```

If you want to "disable" the glob expansion, e.g. get literial `Filename*.txt` by `echo $myvariable`, you can either `set -f` or just wrap the variable by double quote: `echo "$myvariable"`.

To maniuplate the text you can do something like:

```
for f in $myvariable; do echo $f"whatever_like_zip"; done
```

if you want to do some text substitution, you can

```
for ... echo ${f/%txt/zip} ; done
```

It will change all `txt` file name to `zip`.

Also if you want to rename the file, change the above `echo...` into

```
mv "$f" "yourNewNameHere"
```

Anyway by reading your question I'm not quite clear, what do you really want.

Answer (score -1):

Yuo can use sed

try this

```
file="test.txt"
newext=$(echo "$file" | sed -e "s|txt|zip|g")
echo $newext
```